# creating a JDialog with multiple, selectable image items

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jdialog, jlayeredpane

I'm attempting to create a JDialog frame that will have a background image and an interactive JPanel above that.  In this context, the JDialog would represent a 'combat' field where units would be able to be selected and moved.  The game is space based so there will be an ArrayList of ships and possibly a planet object to defend.

I've been able to override paintComponent to draw a rough circle representing a 'planet' but couldn't get the background JLabel image to show.  Then I could get the background JLabel to show but couldn't see the circles.  Ideally, I want to replace the circles with actual images for each ship type and unique for planets.  I'm open to other methods than using this JDialog/JLayered/Customer JPanel if there is a better way to accomplish this.  I've been working on this for more hours than I can count.

I've created a JDialog, added a JLayeredPane and set a JLabel within that for the background.  I've written a custom class extending JPanel that would be added to the JLayeredPane above the JLabel, which draws circles for the planet and units.

[image]

The reason I chose a JPanel is so I can check for mouse events to determine what the player is selecting (the planet to add resources) or a ship (for movement and attack).

for the custom JPanel I've written this simple extension:

```
public class SectorPnl extends javax.swing.JPanel implements MouseInputListener, ActionListener {

private int                 circleY, circleX, circleRadius;
private Sector              sector;
private Shape               planetShape;
private Shape               shipShape;
private Ship                ship;
private Planet              planet;
private Invasion            inv;
private ArrayList<ShipType> shipBuild;

public SectorPnl(Sector sector, Invasion inv)
{
    initComponents();

    this.sector = sector;
    this.inv = inv;
    this.planet = sector.getPlanet();
    shipBuild = new ArrayList();

    Timer update = new Timer(28, this);
    update.start();

    if ( sector.hasPlanet() )
    {
        circleRadius = (int) sector.getPlanet().getPlanetRadius();
        circleX = (int) sector.getPlanet().getPositionX();
        circleY = (int) sector.getPlanet().getPositionY();
        planetShape = new Ellipse2D.Double(circleX, circleY, circleRadius,
                circleRadius);
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponents(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    if ( planetShape != null)
    {
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.fill(planetShape);
        g2.draw(planetShape);
    }
    if ( shipShape != null )
    {
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.fill(shipShape);
        g2.draw(shipShape);
    }
}
```

And this is the lines for adding it to the JDialog:

```
  sectorDlg.setTitle(sector.getName());

  sectorDlg.setVisible(true);
  sectorDlg.setSize(800,800); 

  SectorPnl sectorPnl = new SectorPnl(sector, inv);
  sectorPnl.addMouseListener(sectorPnl);
  sectorPnl.addMouseMotionListener(sectorPnl);

  sectorLayer.setLayer(sectorPnl, 100);
  sectorLayer.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 800);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for a JLabel to show both an icon and text, but I think you have to specify the relative position of the icon and the text.

```
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif");
. . .
label1 = new JLabel("Image and Text",
                    icon,
                    JLabel.CENTER);
//Set the position of the text, relative to the icon:
label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
```

This was taken from Oracle's [How to use labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html).

I don't know what happens if you try to set the background and foreground colors.

I think you would be better off if you used a JPanel as a canvas, and just drew the icons and text where you wanted them.  You can process mouse clicks on the JPanel.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the background image displaying now and having the 'ship' and 'planet' painted on top.  I'm still trying to determine how to pick a mouse event when an Image is clicked though.

I've added a few new variables:

```
    private Image               bgImage;
    private Image               shipImage;
```

For correcting the background issue I added these lines after initComponents();

```
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("sector_Bg1.png"));
    bgImage = ii.getImage();
```

I've changed my paintComponent method to add ship icons (in .png or .jpg format) and paint them as well.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponents(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D g4 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g3.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);

    if ( planetShape != null)
    {
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.fill(planetShape);
        g2.draw(planetShape);
    }
    for ( Ship s : sector.getShips() )
    {
        ImageIcon si = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("isd.png"));
        shipImage = si.getImage();
        g3.drawImage(shipImage, (circleX + shipImage.getHeight(null)), circleY, null);
    }
}
```

Now....how to pick up mouse events within a drawn Image?

Comment: `g3.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);` should be `g3.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, this);`

Comment: *"Now....how to pick up mouse events within a drawn Image?"*  That should be on another question if this post is the answer to this question.  If this post is *not* an answer to the question, the information should be [edited into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16248935/418556).